# Push notification badge

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am pushing several messages form my server to the iPhone. When I am pushing I'm setting the badge value as 1. As there are several independent tasks in the server there may be situational where server pushes messages to same phone but the badge will be 1 cos as those are independent tasks I cannot increment the badge and send. So I want to know whether this badge is incremented in the iPhone side or do we have to push the badge value appropriately?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The badge value will be whatever you set it to, it won't increment on the device automatically. Your server logic needs to keep track of the proper badge count and send it appropriately.

Services like [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) offer solutions for auto-incrementing badge counts on their server, which may or may not assist you.

Also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942605/push-notification-badge-auto-increment).