# APNS-java does not increment badge number on iOS application

Tags: java, ios, apple-push-notifications, badge

I am using [java-apns](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns) library. JavaDoc for method `badge` from `PayloadBuilder` class states that:

> Sets the notification badge to be displayed next to the application
>   icon. The passed value is the value that should be displayed (it will
>   be added to the previous badge number), and badge of 0 clears the
>   badge indicator.

However, passing always 1 to method does not increment badge number on application icon. It's stuck on 1 (or on the number I pass).

Is it possible to solve that or documentation is wrong? I do not want to keep server-side how many unread notifications are on client and manage that number on my own as work-around. Since I know that notifications can be discarded by Apple if device is not reachable for a long time and so is easy to get out of synch.

An example of my code:

```
PayloadBuilder payloadBuilder = APNS.newPayload().alertBody("Test message");
payloadBuilder.actionKey("OK");
payloadBuilder.badge(1);
```

and JSON payload from console:

```
Payload={"aps":{"alert":{"body":"Test message","action-loc-key":"OK"},"badge":1}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to include the  "badge" in your payload, it doesn't get accumulated.

I guess you need to set: `payloadBuilder.badge(15); // 15 is the total`

See this apple [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html).

Comment: I can tell man, but the device updates the badge according to the "badge" value in the payload, so I don't think the library you use has anything to do rather than creating the payload and send it.

Comment: Looking also at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942605/push-notification-badge-auto-increment, it seems that it's not possible at all.

Comment: You can't increment the badge number, only set it. They probably did this because it's a bad idea to increment it anyway since push notifications aren't always received. You should track the number server-side.